# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' при попытке просмотра HLS стрима в video.js

Tags: javascript, html5, flash, видео

Через веб видео плеер video.js + videojs-contrib-hls пытаюсь проигрывать HLS стрим http://82.76.249.77/digi24edge/digi24hdhqhls/playlist.m3u8.

В консоле получаю ошибку

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://82.76.249.77/digi24edge/digi24hdhqhls/playlist.m3u8. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed access.`

Указанный линк рабочий, он проигрывается в VLC плеере.

Никак не могу понять про CORS. Access-Control-Allow-Origin надо прописывать на странице где установлен video.js плеер, или же эти заголовки должны быть на том сервере, где видео стрим?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот заголовок должен отдавать сервер в случае кросс-доменного запроса.

Заголовок выглядит так `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.your.domain.name` или, например, так `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Инструкции как настроить веб-сервер (любой) [лежат тут](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

Comment: Вот я и не могу понять какой именно сервер: там где расположена страничка с video.js плеером, или же там где расположен стрим?

Comment: вот этот http://82.76.249.77/digi24edge...

Comment: Получается, что если у меня нет доступа к серверу, где расположен стрим, я на своем сайте (на другом домене) никак не могу из-за CORS проигрывать этот стрим?

Comment: @p2mbot, не совсем. проблема не в потоке, он будет проигрываться, проблема в запросе плейлиста аяксом. браузер не обработает ответ с другого домена если в ответе нет этого заголовка. в схожей ситуации я на своей стороне в nginx сделал location который проксировал ответ 2рого сервера, т.е. получал ответ со своего домена.

Comment: Благодарствую, идея с проксированием ответа от второго сервера может решить проблему.